# Swing: JTable Columns

Tags: java, swing

Here is my problem. I have to create a `Jtable` with 3 columns (Drink, Price, Quantity) then, I have to create a button "add" and a button "total" with a `JOptionPane` for the result total.

Here is a visual:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ589.png)

I will wish to create a button "total" (with a JOptionPane) in including the price * the quantity. But, I don't know how to do.

Here is my codes.

**JFrame**

```
private void jButtonAjoutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String tmp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter your drink please : ", "Title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        float p = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter your price please :", "Title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        int quant = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter your quantity please :", "Title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        if (tmp != null)
        {
            myModel.addElement(new Drink(tmp, p, quant));
        } //(tmp != null)

    }                                           

    private void jButtonSumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // Button total
        float result = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < jTable1.getRowCount(); y++)
        {
            result = Float.parseFloat(jTable1.getValueAt(y, 1).toString());
        }

    }
```

**TableModelDrink**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

public class TableModelDrinks extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ArrayList<Drink>  myList = new ArrayList <>();

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int i, int j) {
        switch (j)
        {
            case 0: return myList.get(i).getName();
            case 1: return myList.get(i).getPrice();
            case 2: return myList.get(i).getQuantity();
            default: return null;
        }

    } 

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int j)
    {
        switch (j)
        {
            case 0: return "Drink";
            case 1: return "Price";
            case 2: return "Quantity";
            default: return null;
        }

    }

    public void addElement(Drink elt)
    {
        myList.add(elt);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
        switch (colIndex) {
            case 0:
                myList.get(rowIndex).setName((String) value);
                break;

            case 1:
                myList.get(rowIndex).setPrice(Float.parseFloat((String ) value));
                break;

            case 2:
                myList.get(rowIndex).setQuantity(Integer.parseInt((String ) value));
                break;
        }
        fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }
}
```

**Drink**

```
public class Drink {
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private int quantity;

    public Drink(String name, float price, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


}
```

Thank you for your helps

Comment: In your addElement(...) method don't use `fireTableDataChanged(...)`. This causes extra work for the table. The table will recreate all the table columns because it thinks all the data has changed. Instead use `fireTableRowsInserted(...)`. Now only the single row will be repainted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. Simply add following method to your `TableModelDrinks`

```
public Drink drinkAt(int row) {
    return myList.get(row);
}
```

Then you can implement your sum method as followed:

```
private void jButtonSumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    TableModelDrinks model = (TableModelDrinks) jTable1.getModel();
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        Drink d = model.drinkAt(i);
        result += d.getPrice() * d.getQuantity();
    }
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jTable1, "Your total price is: " + format.format(result), "Price", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```